# Javascript getElementById()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

I'm trying to create a generic javascript function that would change attributes on events.

The way it would work is

```
function fooFunction(sourceElement) 
{    
  var newName = sourceElement+'Span';    
  var newElement = document.getElementById(newName);
  //Important line
  newElement.property = "enter properties here";
}
```

and I'd call it with something like

```
<img src="foo.gif" id="foo" name="foo" onmouseover="fooFunction(this.id);"/>
<span id="fooSpan" name="fooSpan">some text here</span>
```

So in theory, when hovering the image, it should change whatever propery I need to change on the fooSpan object. It works in Opera, but on IE it returns a null object.

Any ideas ?

The idea would be that I would have multiple images that would automatically trigger the property change on the associated text span (typically the css style).

Comment: You should reenter the code you inserted as it was lost because you didn't mark it as code.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to change the style attribute. But the object is null to begin with. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Could you post the actual code you're using? Instead of 'newElement.property'.

Comment: @mtranda- what property of the element are you trying to change? there are many style attributes for elements in css, so which one? it would be easier if you would paste actual code of your attempt

Comment: what is the 'null object'?  newElement or newElement.property?

Comment: I tested your code in IE7, and it works. So what is your problem exactly? (I replaced the "newElement.property..." line with "newElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";)

Comment: Please post actual code. Instead of saying 'property'. The line newElement.property = "enter properties here"; looks highly grotesque. and you call it an important line. What an irony! :-) Please post actual line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're getting the ID properly in IE?  Maybe the ID being passed in is null in IE (perhaps this.id isn't working?).

Try calling it like this:

```
<img src="foo.gif" id="foo" name="foo" onmouseover="fooFunction('foo');"/>
```

and see if that helps.  I don't see any reason why getElementById() would fail, so the only thing I can think of is that it's an ID issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be this line won't work in IE. "newElement.property"
I don't know the exact reason.

You can use this instead of that line

newElement.setAttribute(property,"enter properties here");

In the mean time, i am trying to find out the reason behind the error.

Comment: there is nothing called .property. He is just using it as a random substitute string than putting the actual code which may be  .style or .width or something.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would to do something like this.

```
function fooFunction(sourceElement,property,propertyValue) {    
  var newElement = document.getElementById(sourceElement);
  newElement.setAttribute(property,propertyValue);
};
```

And your HTML would look like:

```
<img src="foo.gif" id="foo" name="foo" 
           onmouseover="fooFunction('fooSpan','class','mouseover_span');"/>
<span id="fooSpan" name="fooSpan">some text here</span>
```

Comment: But that totally violates DRY. If he's using a naming scheme (fooSpan, barSpan, etc.) he'll have to type that out every time.

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about that, I was just trying to make a generalized function. He could add an onmouseover and onmouseout function which used fooFunction() as its base. That way your onmouseover and onmouseout functions don't share the same code. I didn't even notice the flaw til you pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd STRONGLY urge you to consider using jQuery's built-in attr() method which integrates the function you want perfectly across browsers and is incredibly easy to use.

Using your example, if you wanted to change the "src" property for "foo", you could do it in a single line of code:

```
$("#foo").attr("src","images/whatever.png");
```

Similarly, if you wanted to change the html WITHIN "fooSpan", all you'd have to do is:

```
$("#fooSpan").html("something else");
```

You can even tie these to events that are going to give you a lot more flexibility than the onmouseover property:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#foo").mouseover(function(){
    $("#fooSpan").html("something else");
    $("#foo").attr("src","images/whatever.png");
    });
});
```